# When I use xcodebuild to create xcframwork I got an error It should be caused by Google WebRTC May I ask how I will resolve this error

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcodebuild, podspec, xcframework

This is the xcodebuild terminal file I am using

```
BUILD_DIR=$(dirname "$PWD")/sdk/xc
PROJECT=$PWD/Example/SDK.xcworkspace
TARGET_DIR=$(dirname "$PWD")/sdk/archives

rm -Rf $TARGET_DIR

mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR

mkdir -p $TARGET_DIR

################ Build  SDK

xcodebuild clean -workspace $PROJECT -scheme SDK

# -arch x86_64 arm64 \    MACH_O_TYPE=staticlib
xcodebuild archive \
    -workspace $PROJECT \
    -scheme SDK  \
    -configuration Release \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -destination='generic/platform=iOS Simulator' \
    -archivePath $BUILD_DIR/SDK.iOS-simulator.xcarchive \
    ENABLE_BITCODE=NO \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES | xcbeautify

xcodebuild archive \
    -workspace $PROJECT \
    -scheme SDK  \
    -configuration Release \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    -destination='generic/platform=iOS' \
    -archivePath $BUILD_DIR/SDK.iOS.xcarchive \
    ENABLE_BITCODE=NO \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
    BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES | xcbeautify

 
xcodebuild -create-xcframework   -framework "$BUILD_DIR/SDK.iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/SDK.framework" \
                                 -framework "$BUILD_DIR/SDK.iOS-simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/SDK.framework" \
                                -output "$TARGET_DIR/SDK.xcframework" | xcbeautify

rm -Rf $BUILD_DIR
```

Then, during the compilation process, an error message is obtained

```
❌ ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '/Example/Pods/GoogleWebRTC/Frameworks/frameworks/WebRTC.framework/WebRTC' for architecture arm64
❌ clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/codeing/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDK-bhqgqpyahwxtbjcwvmtbmnnjbqeu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/SDK/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/SDK.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Binary/SDK normal arm64 (in target 'SDK' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I have also tried using - arch x86_ 64 and MACH_ O_ TYPE=staticlib.  Yes, it does not have any error messages when it comes to XCODEBUILD, but I will give me an error when I push to CocoAPODS.

very bad headache now It has been tossing and turning for several days May I ask how to solve these problems?

Comment: The reason is WebRTC.framework was only built for architecture `arm64`. I think you should try WebRTC.xcframework

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I already know it was caused by WebRTC But I searched for a lot of information online to solve this problem but couldn't solve it Do you have any reference materials or are you willing to post the code to solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Do the framework need to support iOS Simulator? You can remove `-framework "$BUILD_DIR/SDK.iOS-simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/SDK.framework" \` line in the file

Comment: Yes, it would be best to support iOS Simulator, but I'm not sure if my requirement is correct at the moment. It was developed to support iOS Simulator.